# Strategy to synchronize 2 sortedsets in redis?

Tags: redis, sortedset

I have 2 sorted sets:

`mainSet`: which contains a list of `<score, id>`

`userSet`: which contains some of items filtered from `mainSet` based on certain ruless. (Each user in the system will have an userSet with userId as key)

If there are some changes in the `mainSet` and very likely item order will be re-sorted, (like score updated, new items added), then I want to update the `userSet` accordingly.

For example,

```
mainSet<key, 1, id1>
mainSet<key, 2, id2>
mainSet<key, 3, id3>
mainSet<key, 4, id4>

userSet<userKey, 2, id2>
userSet<userKey, 3, id3>
```

Items in the `mainSet` will be added/updated in the `userSet` based on some filtered rules

Currently, to make sure items in the `userSet` up to date with the `mainSet` (for example, the score of items changed), I have to traverse all items in the `mainSet`, check filtered rules, and re-add in the `userSet` but it takes around 250 ms for 200 items in the `mainSet`. (The mainSet may have max of 1000 items).

I want to know if there are any better approaches for my case?

Comment: Could you provide a more concrete example? If you are storing the same unique id in each set, why would you need to "re-add" anything to userSet? Is the score the same in both sets? Why would you do that? I'm confused what your current solution is doing.

Comment: I have added examples and clarify some confused points. It really helpful if you could give me some advice

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Redis Keyspace Notifications](http://redis.io/topics/notifications)? Keyspace notifications is a feature available since 2.8.0. If you add a listener to your main set, and for each received event validate whether the object should be moved in or out of the subset, then the system should handle the changes automatically.